# Send batched data to Google Calendar with Scala/Spray

Tags: scala, google-calendar-api, spray

We are successfully sending data for new, changed, and removed events to Google Calendar from a Scala app using Spray HTTP. However, we are currently sending one event per request, and this becomes very inefficient when there are multiple events for the current user. In these cases we would like to send batched data, as described here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch

The documentation begins with:

> A batch request is a single standard HTTP request containing multiple
>   Google Calendar API calls, using the multipart/mixed content type.
>   Within that main HTTP request, each of the parts contains a nested
>   HTTP request.

Since we are already using spray http we would like to use its support for multipart/mixed requests (`spray.http.MultipartContent`) but it isn't clear that this is possible since the parts must consist of one or more `spray.http.BodyPart` instances and there doesn't seem to be a way to turn a `spray.http.HttpRequest` into a `BodyPart`.

Has anyone successfully done this? We are also taking a look at the Google API Client for Java but would rather not go down that path if there is a more Scala-friendly way to do it.

Comment: spray is deprecated. Please use akka-http instead. You'll need `FormData` or `Multipart.FormData` and `Http().cachedHostConnectionPool()`.